# merging 2 users table with overlaping primary key value

Tags: mysql

I am in search of best way to merge 2 MySQL tables with overlaping primary key value (users_id)

Both tables have different structure,

MEMEBR(member_id,memeber_email,member_dob,....) currently Next Auto Increment Value 27014

USER(users_id, email,name,dob,.....) currently Next Auto Increment Value 23734

Both tables belongs to different applications, and have many log/transaction tables with referred primary key value (Member_id and users_id).

I already write query to select data from USER and Insert Into MEMBER, but main issue is overlapping IDS. 
At first i think to append all records of USERS after the last record in MEMBER, but this generate new IDS, and cause inconsistencies in USER application refereed table.

2nd i think to store an extra field Users_id in MEMBER to track related records in USER application.

Now what to store for MEMBER application users in this extra field. As Now merged user will use both applications seamless, so it need a value in this field, of course same as member_id.

So NOW,
MEMBER(memeber_id,Users_id,email,....)
1,1,a@b.com
2,2,b@b.com
.
.
.
27014,27014,z@b.com   here end MEMBER record
27015,1,aa@bb.com     1st record from Users Table

Now i have in consistency here.

User_id 1  exist in both member_id 1 (1,1,a@b.com) and member_id 27015 (27015,1,aa@bb.com)

To fix this another point in my mind is to put 0 in users_id field for all existing member application and future users, means just saving existing users_id from USER application.

Help if you understand and face the same issue, or can think as me.

May some one ask about the question or REAL question, so.

QUESTION:
As explained in above problem, what can be the best way to handle overlapping id when merging 2 users tables from 2 different application, that user will access both application seamlessly.

Any help appreciated.

Let me know if need further information.

Answer (score 1):

After merging one user record it's current ID and new ID. Then update these IDs in all tables:

```
UPDATE table1 set UserID=:newID where UserID=:oldID
UPDATE table2 set UserID=:newID where UserID=:oldID
etc.
```

Repeat.

Comment: is it final solution? I will do it if no hope for any other short cut.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do the following:

1. create separate table with new primary/autoincrement key and all necessary columns for holding merge results
2. Populate new table with results from both tables thus creating new IDs
3. Update all tables referring to MEMBER and USER with new IDs (this might also include removing/recreating foreign key constraints to point to a new merged table)
4. remove old tables.

Comment: it will need a lot of care and time, Any further suggestion.